# How to Create List of Strings Seperated By Commas

Tags: python

I need to create a list of `IDs` with each value separated by commas to be passed as a parameter in a RESTful `API` call. The `API` supports filtering records by `ID` in the following format: `endpoint/id in (1, 2, 3)`. The values also need to be `strings`. How can I create a list of manipulate a list to match the query string parameters format?

Comment: the way this question stands at the moment, telling you to just *type the list with the keyboard* would be a valid answer in my mind.. You have to be more specific with your problem

Comment: If you have a list `[1,2,3]` in python, then you can do `",".join(mylist)` to get `"1,2,3"`

Comment: Correct - by definition a list in python is separated by commas. 

'Explicit is better than Implicit' - The "separated by commas" piece, although redundant, only clarifies the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you were looking for?

```py
ids = ["0001", "0002", "0003"]
ids = ids
my_id_list = ','.join(ids)

print(my_id_list)

>>> '0001,0002,0003'
```

---

If you needed the quotes around the items, you could do this...

```py
ids = ["0001", "0002", "0003"]
my_id_list = '"' + '","'.join(ids) + '"'

print(my_id_list)

>>> '"0001","0002","0003"'
```

---

If you wanted something more like the format that you type into your python script, you could literally just `str(...)` your id list.

```py
ids = ["0001", "0002", "0003"]
str(ids)

>>> "['0001', '0002', '0003']"
```

Comment: the first solution you provided works great, thanks!